# what happens to completed Magento orders when you delete those products from your db?

Tags: magento

If we delete products from our database, does it have an effect on completed orders which included those products?

How does it effect Magento reports?

Are such potential problems with deleting products?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you delete products via Magento admin, it won't have harmful effect on completed orders which included those products and it will also not affect standard Magento reports.

Required information for orders and reports for the deleted products remain stored in the following database table: `sales_flat_order_item`. Here you can find informations that Magento requires to display in orders and reports, like:

```
order_id, store_id, product_id, product_type, sku, name, description
```

and more. You can check by looking at the database table structure.

This may not hold true for third-party extensions which should be investigated if they are trying to get further product details for an order or report, but as long as we are talking about a clean Magento install there shall be no worry about breaking reports and orders.

Comment: How I can get list of orders which contain _deleted_ products?

Answer (score 0):

Normaly the products are stocked in a table called `sales_flat_order_item` that as no link with the table catalog_product_entity even if the product_id is set. to answer, your question, I am almost sure that "no" but I cannot be 100% sure. I am wondering why you want to delete products when you can deactivate them and be sure to keep some integrity in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting/editing products will not have any effect on orders.

sales_flat_order_item is the table where order data is populated.

Apart from product Id sales_flat_order_item does not have any other ID details.

Also there is SKU entry in sales_flat_order_item so product ID is more for reference only.